# Calculating convolution of two function in matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, convolution

I need to calculate convolution of functions:
f(x)=1 when -1< x <2, 0 otherwise
g(x)=sgn(x)*dirac(abs(x)-1)

I've got this code:

```
Fs=1;
t=-10:1/Fs:10;
d=dirac(abs(t)-1);
s=sign(t);
x=d.*s;
x2=1*(t>-1 & t<2);
spl=conv(x,x2,'same');
disp(spl);
```

But what I get is a lot of NaN values.
Where is my mistake? What should I change?

Comment: The question seems to be asking about a dirac delta, in continuous time—an infinitely tall and infinitely thin function—which is an analytical concept that doesn’t translate well into discrete time for solving with Matlab. Unless this is specifically a discrete-time problem, I suggest solving this analytically, or symbolically with a computer algebra system?

Comment: I've already solved this problem analytically. What i need to do now is to solve it with matlab someway.

Comment: It seems you are trying to carry out the convolution using the symbolic library. However, the symbolic library has no `conv` function, `conv` is for discrete numerical convolution. If you want to verify your integration, rewrite the convolution as an integral and use the function `int` for symbolic integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a way of estimating the solution in discrete-time domain. This requires a couple of changes to your code:

1. Increase the sample rate `Fs` to preserve more bandwidth. I used 100x below.
2. Replace Dirac delta function by Kronecker delta to enable discrete-time modeling.

The modified code and the results are as follows:

```
Fs=100; % use higher sampling rate
t=-10:1/Fs:10;
d=(abs(t)-1)==0; % use kronecker delta function for discrete-time simulation
s=sign(t);
x=d.*s;
x2=1*(t>-1 & t<2);
spl=conv(x,x2,'same');

% plots to visualize the results
figure;
subplot(3,1,1);
plot(t, x2);
ylabel('f(x)');
subplot(3,1,2);
plot(t, x);
ylabel('g(x)');
subplot(3,1,3);
plot(t, spl);
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('convolution');
```

[image: results]

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
Fs=1;
t=-10:1/Fs:10;
g=t;
g(g~=1)=0;  %g function
s=sign(t);
x=g.*s;
f=t;
f(f>-1 & f<2)=1;
f(f~=1)=0;  %f function
x2=f;
spl=conv(x,x2,'same');
disp(spl)
```